# Azure Static Web App when linked to API Management breaks the API when authenticated

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-static-web-app

I have a Static Web App which I have [linked to APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-api-management#link-an-azure-api-management-service). All works well.

But then when I use auth to log in, */.auth/login/aad*, and I'm redirected back to the web app the request to the API now fails with a HTTP status code 500. Looking at the browser's developer console when I inspect the API response I see the [default ASP.NET yellow screen of death].

[image]

When I log back out then everything works again.

If I link directly to an Azure Function App instead of the APIM then everything works when I'm both logged in and when I'm logged out.

Any ideas on what is causing the error when logged in and linked to APIM?

Answer (score 0):

I determined the issue exists when using the APIM Consumption SKU but not when using the Developer SKU. There must be a limitation when linking a SWA to a Consumption APIM and when using the built-in SWA auth.